# Reputation requirement for a self answer?

Tags: support, reputation, self-answer

I have a question on AskUbuntu which I managed to solve myself with some guidance from another user, He suggested that I self answer my question and provided this link as reference: https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer
According to the link, there is a 15 rep requirement to self answer your post, however said user believes that to be incorrect and suggested I post here for confirmation.
Is this the case? Does one require a minimum number of rep in order to answer there own question? If so, can I ask what the justification behind that is as it seems a bit silly. I can understand restricting answers from new users, but surely a self answer is a different case entirely.

Answer (score 6):

The rep requirement is for posting a question and its answer together. (That's what the checkbox on that page refers to: an option to compose the answer together with the question before positing both simultaneously.) It doesn't apply to posting an answer after posting the question. (Though a separate requirement means that you can't *accept* a self-answer immediately.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, looking into it further it seems I had an extension which modified the CSS of the page hiding the button to post an answer. Thats my bad.